# Run .bat file from Jenkins

Tags: java, batch-file, tomcat, jenkins

I'm trying to run the file with [Managed Script Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Managed+Script+Plugin)

When I run, there is error:

```
FailedConsole Output

Started by user anonymous
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace C:\Users\*****\.hudson\jobs\dfs\workspace
[workspace] $ cmd /c call C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.63\temp\hudson5830491027958954227.bat

C:\Users\*****\.hudson\jobs\dfs\workspace>call "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.63-jenkins\bin\startup.bat" 
Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\java.exe"" was unexpected at this time.
Build step 'Execute managed windows batch' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

The same error is, when I call java class from Jenkins. In the java class is:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\apache-tomcat-7.0.63-jenkins\\bin\\startup.bat");
```

Any Idea?
I just want to start/stop tomcat

Answer (score 0):

You are running

```
cmd /c call C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.63\temp\hudson5830491027958954227.bat
```

"call" has no meaning in a command window only in a batch file. Try skipping the "call" in your commandline.

Comment: Same situation:

`Started by user anonymous
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace C:\Users\*****\.hudson\jobs\dfs\workspace
[workspace] $ cmd /c call C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.63\temp\hudson6306847186713865408.bat

C:\Users\******\.hudson\jobs\dfs\workspace>"C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.63-jenkins\bin\startup.bat"
Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\java.exe"" was unexpected at this time.
Build step 'Execute managed windows batch' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE`

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think the best way to execute batch/shell scripts with Jenkins is to use their plugins.

About your case, the plugin you are using opens a cmd to execute the batch script, so you don't need to specify how to open it, `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.63-jenkins\bin\startup.bat` is enough. In the java example don't use start.

Comment: Yes, I tried with default plugin in jenkins - same result. 
If this plugin opens "cmd", why is not working with this `C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.63-jenkins\bin\startup.bat`?

Now I run it via cmd, but there is error: `The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program`

If I set catalina_home - when I start tomcat6, instead tomcat7, every tomcat starts with the path in catalina_home - so this will be problem

Comment: The jenkins cmd (or any cmd in that sense) starts with its own context, that stores the variables as CATALINA_HOME. If you set CATALINA_HOME in the beginning of the script it wont be present after the cmd exits.